# javascript array to formatted string

Tags: javascript

In javascript I have an array like

`psi=["www.google.com","www.facebook.com","www.collegehumor.com"]`

I want to turn it to a formatted string like

```
var final=<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">www.google.com</a></br>,<a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank">www.facebook.com</a></br>,<a href="www.collegehumor.com" target="_blank">www.collegehumor.com</a></br>
```

so I can send from server to client something like

```
//websockets, btw...
connection.send('Search Results'+t_name+'</br>Links'+final+'</br>');
```

and it will render just the working links.

Something like

```
www.google.com
www.facebook.com
www.collegehumor.com
```

I know there is the `toString()`. But no luck with that. I cant make it create working links.

I tried to implement a `for` inside the `connection.send` but Dreamweaver says there is a syntax error. That's why I try to convert the array to formatted string.

Any advise?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a job for a template engine (my personal favorite is [doT](http://olado.github.io/doT/) because it's fast, it generates efficient templates, and it's tiny).

Comment: Can you not build the string in a loop using `+=` and then pass it?

Comment: Add "http://" before www, otherwise it will fail. Also, when declaring the variable "final", as it is a string, it needs to be between quotes and escape those quotes that are form the text itself: `var final="<a href=\"http://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\">www.google.com</a>, ...";`

Comment: @AlejandroIván Alternatively, you can avoid the escaping of `"` by simply wrapping the enter `final` string value with `'`.

Comment: @ajp15243 true. I'm just used to it :)

Comment: the `string` object also has a function called `link(url)`, that returns a HTML string containing your link, ready to insert into the DOM: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Strings_Reference#quickIDX21

Comment: @Zim84 yes, but does it have a way to add the "target" property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var psi=["www.google.com","www.facebook.com","www.collegehumor.com"]
var str = '';
for(var i in psi)
{
    str += ',<a href="http://'+psi[i]+'" target="_blank">'+psi[i]+'</a><br>';
}
str = str.substr(1);
```

Alternate version using the `string.link()` method mentioned by Zim84 in the comments above:

```
var psi=["www.google.com","www.facebook.com","www.collegehumor.com"]
var str = '';
for(var i in psi)
{
    var url = psi[i];
    str += ','+url.link('http://'+url)+'<br>';
}
str = str.substr(1).replace('">','" target="_blank">');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var final = "";
for (var i = 0; i < psi.length; i++)
{
    var linkWithHttp = "http://" + psi[i];
    final += "<a href=\"" + linkWithHttp + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + psi[i] + "</a><br />,";
}

// Remove the last "," if you added, at least, one element
if (psi.length > 0)
{
    final = final.substring(0, final.length - 1);
}

// Now final is like what you want
// Send it using connection.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use jQuery it's a piece of cake:

```
var final = $.map(psi, function(link) {
  return '<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + link + '</a>';
}).join('<br />,');
```

Comment: _ECMAScript5's_ `Array.prototype.map` would take exactly the same _function_.

Comment: Paul S is correct.  If you don't care about IE 8 that would work, but you'd have to do the join manually (it wouldn't be hard, though).

Comment: what do you mean "have to do the _join_ manually? Array's **[_join_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** has been part of _JavaScript_ since _ECMAScript 1st Edition_ - pre IE6

Comment: I didn't see it in the documentation, but I guess it was only showing the NEW stuff in ECMAScript5 on the page I was viewing.  I've gotten so used to using jQuery for everything that I don't even know what's in the language itself!